# Transfer amount to credit card from paypal

Tags: paypal, credit-card

I have stuck into the problem of related to transfer amount back to credit card from paypal when user cancel his/her transaction. I don't want to use paypal refund feature in our application. My client requires to send back amount at the same time when user cancel his/her transaction. 
Can anyone guide me to complete this feature or is there any API to solve such type of feature.

Thanks in advance.
Dewan

Comment: What language are you developing in?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to use paypal refund feature in our application. My
>   client requires to send back amount at the same time when user cancel
>   his/her transaction.

### How PayPal Refunds

You don't want to use PayPal's refund feature, but you want to send money back to the buyer? This is called a refund. I am sure you are mistaking how PayPal refunds money. If the user pays with a credit card, they are refunded to their credit card. If they pay with a bank account or PayPal account, they are refunded to their PayPal account.

### API calls that refund buyers

1. [DoNonReferencedCredit would refund to a credit card you specify, everytime, and you do not need a transaction ID.](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/dononreferencedcredit-api-nvp)

   - In a scenario where the buyer no longer has a card that was
     associated with a transaction, or the time allotted for a refund in
     PayPal has passed, you would want to use the DoNonReferencedCredit
     API.
2. [RefundTransaction would refund the funding source as described in the "How PayPal Refunds" paragraph.](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/refundtransaction-api-nvp)

   - If your main concern is to issue a refund, via API, you have a transaction ID (you say a payment has been completed so you should have a transaction ID), *AND* PayPal's refund time has not passed,  you should use the RefundTransaction API.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to use something like [DoNonReferencedCredit](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1262) from the paypal API - but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: This API does need approval from PayPal customer service and I do not think it is guaranteed for everyone. I expanded on your answer with my own.